# D3 Force Layout - Repelling Force on Update

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I have a D3 force layout.  Several of the nodes start in same location, but on load the force layout repels them so they do not overlap.  I then allow the user to change the dimensional value of the node which causes re-positioning.  However the re-positioning does not repel and the nodes completely overlap.

I have not been able to figure out how to "reheat" the layout with the new positions.  There is a fair amount of code, but I suspect the issue is in the tick(e) function or in re-referencing that function when the update occurs.  Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GaryGeo/mt0q5tmx/

```
function tick(e) { 
 node
      .each(gravity(.2 * e.alpha))
      .each(collide(.5))
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x+ "," + d.y + ")"; });
}
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas or help.

Comment: You can use [`force.start()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#start) to restart the layout after altering the nodes.

Comment: If I put it in my redraw function it does not have access to the force object.  I did make some progress, but commenting out the force charge and gravity to rely on the custom functions, but it is not relocating the nodes correctly.

Comment: So give yourself access to it in your redraw function... either pass it in as an argument, or create both functions in the same scope.

Comment: I have tried passing it, making it a global variable, etc, but no luck.  I am assuming it is because the redraw occurs on the change event.

Comment: I believe I finally understand what my problem was.  I was using an svg:g (group element) and those can only positioned with transform functions and not be set by x-y coordinates.  I suspect that the grouped nodes do not work with the standard force layout.